# process a directory of files using python

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I have a directory and I want to pick every file within that directory and run a python code on it:
So I do the following

```
for file in os.listdir('/Users/Desktop/Xfiles'):
     os.system('/sw/bin/python2.7 pythonCode.py /Users/Desktop/Xfiles/file')
```

This does not work, I want to process the "file" from the listdir....how can I do that?

Comment: I think this is a common mistake when using Python when one comes from a language like Perl or Bash which allows you to place the variable inside the quotes.  Can you change the title to something about the actual issue you were having so other new users can find this?  Something like "How do I insert a Python variable into a quoted string?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path passed to the `os.system` is hard coded. You should pass `filename`.

```
dirpath = '/Users/Desktop/Xfiles'
for filename in os.listdir(dirpath):
    os.system('/sw/bin/python2.7 pythonCode.py {}/{}'.format(dirpath, filename))
```

- Don't use `file` as variable name. It shadows builtin [`file`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) function.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out !

Answer (score 0):

You can do string interpolation with

```
file = "myfilename"
"some text {}".format(file)
# white should result in "some text myfilename"
```

But for manipulating paths, the best way is to use

```
os.path.join('/Users/gchella1/Desktop/forGeorge/Xfiles/', file)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to put "file" out of the quotes ?

```
for file in os.listdir('/Users/gchella1/Desktop/forGeorge/Xfiles'):
    os.system('/sw/bin/python2.7 pythonCode.py /Users/gchella1/Desktop/forGeorge/Xfiles/'+file)
```

this works for me.

```
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    os.system('ls '+file)
```